# Chrome VS Firefox 1 px different in link

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Hello everyone how can I fix one pixel difference with Chrome and Firefox? My menu links seem in Chrome correctly but in Firefox my menu links are 1 px smaller than Chrome

Here is CSS:

```
ul#menu {
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top:-3px;
    margin-left:7px;
    float:left;
    height:34px;
    display: inline-block; 
}

ul#menu li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Museo300Regular';
    font-size:15px;
    font-style:normal;
    line-height: 1;
}

ul#menu li a {
    background-image:url(../../images2/images/menu_bg_normal.jpg); 
    background-repeat: repeat;
    padding:5px 23px 6px 23px; /*üst sol alt sağ */
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    color: #FEFEFF;
    cursor:pointer; 
}

.deneme 
{
    width:964px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Here is the Html Part:

```
<div class="deneme">
    <ul id="menu">         
     <li><a>Başkan</a></li>
     <li><a>Meclis</a></li>
     <li><a>Enc&#252;men</a></li>
     <li><a>Kurumsal</a></li>
     <li><a>Maltepe</a></li>
     <li><a>Etkinlikler</a></li>
     <li><a>İhaleler</a></li>
     <li><a>E-Belediye</a></li>
     <li><a id="link">Linkler</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Mm very strange. By the way it is NOT 1px smaller, it is 1px shifted down in Firefox, the height is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 3: added images to proof the height is the same...

LARGE VIEW

[image]

CLOSE DETAIL:

[image]

EDIT 2:
This is identical to your first code, and renders identical in both Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/qavB6/4/

Added

```
ul#menu li {
/*...*/
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 4px;
}
```

and `line-height: 35px;` to `ul#menu li a {`.

Enjoy...

EDIT:

Setting the line-height under a certain value, it renders in the same way on Firefox and Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/qavB6/3/

I don't know why, but digging deeper i discovered that setting `line-height: 38px;` or `line-height: 37px;`
doesn't change line-height in Chrome, while it changes on Firefox.

You can see a difference in Chrome between `36px` and `37px`, or between `38px` and `39px`, but not between `37px` and `38px`. That's where the odd behaviour begins...

Comment: I have check with firefox and chrome still same problem you can check your fiddle with chrome and firefox. In Chrome your fiddle menu 85x28 in Firefox 87x29

Comment: I've edited the answer, can you check the described behaviour ?

Comment: Yes I understood what you mean but still need a solution :)

Comment: Try to keep line-height less than 37px, and to use margin-top and margin-bottom to distantiate elements

Comment: Yeap I have checked your edited fiddle as you say I have to set less than 37 px and the line height 34px and I have checked the size in Chrome 85x28 in Firefox 87x29

Comment: I start thinking it is your debug system that shows 1px of different. I'll attach a picture of the two browsers opened side by side, the height is definitely the same, no matter what firebug or chrome inspector says... (i was checking only the height)

Comment: Allright I understood why this strange different is happen because of Chrome and Firefox are rendering the px differently also padding so the solution is using  like for example margin-left:10% instead of px

Answer (score 0):

This code is targeting only Firefox with CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
h1 {
    color: red;
}
}
</style>
```

Use this code to separate the css for Firefox, Add your code instead of h1 for that pixel perfection.

Comment: Same problem I have added menu css properties instead of h1 but I get same result 1px difference